# Do Timers work when started from a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I've got a timer that won't trigger the associated function when the time runs out. I did set a `Tick` event. I set the `Interval` property to `12000` and I did `myTimerObject.Start();`.

I did however set off this timer in a seperate thread (somewhere in a `BackgroundWorker`). My theory is that even though the timer seems to start correctly, the thread is destroyed once the `BackgroundWorker`'s associated `DoWork` function is done executing and this in turn causes the timer event to be destroyed too.

Is this true? Are there other possible reasons why the timer event doesn't occur?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the timer? What kind of timer is it (System.Threading, System.Windows.Forms, System.Timers). It matters. Please post your code, and read this link while waiting for a response. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pieter, the problem is not the thread from which the Timer is started, but rather the fact that you don't keep a live reference to it, hence it gets garbage collected.

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) on Timer (see note under "Remarks"):

> As long as you are using a Timer, you
>   must keep a reference to it. As with
>   any managed object, a Timer is subject
>   to garbage collection when there are
>   no references to it. The fact that a
>   Timer is still active does not prevent
>   it from being collected.

Comment: You said it so much more eloquently :-)